# How to connect ZYNQ development board in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am running Vivado 2021 on Ubuntu 20.04. I am not able to connect hardware, in which Vivado recognize the connected board. If I run "dmesg | grep tty" to see which port the ZYBO is connected I get the following reply.

```
dmesg | grep tty

[13390.172343] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0 
[13390.172752] ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1 
[13390.640829] usb 3-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0 
[13390.643864] usb 3-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have the terminal output as a code block instead of an image

Comment: It is un-stable. Any idea how to make it stable. I am not able to connect to Target board in Vivado.

Comment: You did not edit the question you added it as a comment.